Invalid CORS request or requests dont work
After building my vite project and integrating it into my java spring boot application. I am messing around with cors configurations. When haven no configuration, I can login via SAML SSO where i have microsoft azure as my service provider, and go to the project. But there only the GET requests work. When applying these cors settings, I cant login anymore and i get a blank page which says "invalid cors request":
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                    config.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:8080"));
                    config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
                    config.setAllowCredentials(true); // Allow cookies or authentication headers
                    config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-Requested-With"));
                    return config;
                }))
                .csrf().disable() // Disable CSRF 
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/saml2/**").permitAll() // Allow SAML endpoints
                        .requestMatchers("/login/**").permitAll() // Allow SAML endpoints
                        .requestMatchers("https://localhost:8080/**").permitAll() // Allow SAML endpoints
                        .anyRequest().authenticated() // Adjust based on your requirements
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}

Besides the Security config. Everything else works perfectly fine. I used this config for developing too, but now where SAML and vite are both connected to the backend, at least one of those two doesnt work.
I also tried playing around with the request mathers, added some other stack overflow issues to the code. But nothign worked so far.

Just for testing: Does config.addAllowedOriginPattern("*"); make any change?

I dont recognize any differences.

This part of the config is wrong: .requestMatchers("https://localhost:8080/**").permitAll(). If you monitor the requests in Chrome developer | network and add the URLs that fails to your question, it will be a lot easier to solve this. BR

I went for a different approach. this configuration works now:

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

 
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/error").permitAll() // Allow login and error pages without authentication
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()  // Require authentication for all other requests
                )
                // Enable SAML2 login with default configurations
                .saml2Login(Saml2LoginConfigurer::permitAll)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);  // Disable CSRF for the APIs
//test
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                        .allowedOrigins(
                                "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
                                "http://localhost:5173",
                                "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
                                "http://localhost:8080"
                        )
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "Accept")
                        .allowCredentials(true)
                        .maxAge(3600); 
            }
        };
    }
}





Maybe you should add a sentence about that you added http://127.0.0.1:5173, http://localhost:5173

You dont need localhost:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080 in allowedOrigins so remove them, then in your browser open the developer tools and check the error in the console, it will give you something like "Access to fetch at ... from origin 'localhost:5173'" you will need to add this URL in your config, or you can allow all by adding this .allowedOrigins("*")
